# pycharm - cannot rename/refactor function names

Tags: pycharm

Does pycharm support rename/refactoring of function names (and usage)?
The pop up appears and I'm able to type in the new name but nothing happens after I hit enter.

PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.1
Build #PC-163.9735.8, built on December 14, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86
JVM: OpenJDK Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: Refactoring is not as elegant with functions as it is with variables. I noticed that the refactoring results open up in the 'find' window that stays minized. I then have to open the 'find' window and click on 'Do Refactor' to complete the action.

Comment: Same problem, in addition when this happens if you are able to open the Refactor Preview, there is only a button 'Cancel', no button 'Do Refactor'. I was not able to understand this behavior nor why later I could rename the same method without any problem. Maybe because the file existed in different 'directories' marked as 'source root' under the same 'project', but not sure.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way to rename functions, by doing it through "Change Signature" dialog. This way it refactors immediately instead of having to open up the "Find" tab.